# how to display application in flat list in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

How can I display a list of installed applications in React Native and show their respective icons along with their names?
How to display a list of installed applications in React Native, including:

Retrieving the list of installed applications
Displaying the names and icons of the applications
Implementing the display using the best practices and efficient methodologies in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-installed-application

1. Initialize the library, get list of apps and persist it in some form of state.
2. Create a component with a list that uses the previous saved state to render the elements.

Comment: i also use this package but this librarary did not  show some non system appliaction

Comment: i  would probably used this library: https://github.com/danilrafiqi/react-native-open-application
it is used to open installed application from react native application using packageName of application